# About HTMLUnit and running code

Tags: java, eclipse, htmlunit

I am using HTMLUnit to read content from webpages in eclipse , however when I attempt to run the code a pop up box shows up displaying different "run as" options. I usually choose the default main option to run the code. Is there any way by which i could set something like "always choose this option" so I dont get that box every time I try to run that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the last launched configuration (`Ctrl+F11` in Windows), as stated in the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/menus/run/ref-rll_run.htm).